# PyAudio OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed when running as a systemd service on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, pyaudio

I have encountered a rather peculiar issue while trying to deploy a Python Flask application that uses the PyAudio library to access microphone data. The strange thing is that the application runs perfectly fine when I manually start it using python main.py in the Ubuntu terminal. However, when I set it up as a systemd service and start it with systemctl start, it throws an error.

Here’s the traceback from the system logs:

```
Jun 21 17:48:49 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]: 2023-06-21 17:48:49.770 | DEBUG    | 
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]: Exception in thread Thread-3:
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:   File "/usr/local/python3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:     self.run()
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:   File "/usr/local/python3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:   File "/home/lgfx-voice/Desktop/voice-box/api/receive_audio_data.py", line 48, in receive_data
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:     voice_data = self.stream.read(7680)
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:   File "/home/lgfx-voice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 570, in read
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]:     return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames
Jun 21 17:48:50 lgfxvoice-laptop python3.8[237324]: OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed
```

I’m at a loss as to why the application runs fine when started manually, but not as a systemd service. Could this be related to a difference in environment settings, or maybe some PyAudio limitations when it comes to running under systemd?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to compare the differences in environment variables between launching from the command line and launching as a service. I've also updated system-related dependencies, but none of these have had any effect.